# Can you use a dimmer with a can (recessed) light conversion kit?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

I have a can light (recessed light) that I need to convert to hanging a pendant light. The [conversion kits](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-Recessed-Light-Converter-for-Pendant-or-Light-Fixtures-0101100/204785596) have you plug into the socket, and I am hanging a dimmable LED fixture with a wall dimmer instead of a switch.

Is there any issue with it being dimmable since you're not directly wiring it to the switch? i.e. wiring to the socket adapter -> screwing into the original can light socket.

Here is the socket: [image: socket]

Answer (score 4):

I recently did the exact same thing you're evaluating. We used a conversion kit to install a pendant light above our sink where there was previously a recessed light. As far as dimmability goes, that's mostly up to the switch and the bulb you have, i.e. you have to have a dimmer switch and a compatible, dimmable bulb. We went with Leviton in this particular instance, though we have Lutron dimmer switches elsewhere.

One thing we've noticed, since we're dimming a single bulb, is that we have to find a "sweet spot" on the dimmer to prevent flickering in between brightness levels. It's a minor nuisance for the flexibility of adjusting the brightness.

Comment: Thanks Kyle! Glad to hear that worked for you. I’ll evaluate the dimmers as best I can to check for compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

That connection method should have no effect on dimmability - I've used dozens of replacement can lights that use such an adapter on dimmers, and they work fine.

The more common problem I've experienced with dimming a single fixture with LEDs is that many of the LED-compatible dimmers have a minimum wattage as well as a maximum wattage that they will dim on LEDs, and a single bulb may not draw enough current to meet that minimum.

Comment: Thanks much! The light i'm using i believe draws somewhere around 60 actual watts, it's a bright light, over 6000 lumens. So hopefully that should meet the minimum for a Lutron or Leviton dimmer.

Comment: It looks like I don’t have a ground connection where the socket is, what do I do with the ground wire from the pendant light?

Comment: Normally you pigtail a ground to the can or junction box, but if the can / box isn't grounded that won't help.

Comment: I updated the question and posted a pic of the can and socket. Is there a way to tell if it’s grounded?

Comment: This is the housing spec sheet: https://media.distributordatasolutions.com/JunoLighting/files/File_Juno_6in_IC22_Incandescent_IC_6__IC_Incandescent_Housing.pdf